# rm: cannot remove 'a.txt': Invalid argument

Tags: windows, cygwin, samba, invalid-argument

I have a samba share on the host i.e. \\localhost\share which is mounted on it as X: drive using SMB Global Mapping.

This path is volume mounted inside the containers on the same host as "-v X:\<folder>:C:\<folder>".

Containers are able to access the files from the host's smb share smoothly.
**But** the problem is when I am trying to delete/write those files.

Consider the following 3 scenarios:

1. ***With Powershell.exe*** :) 
   This is able to delete & write into the files inside C:\<folder> properly.
2. ***With Cygwin 2.4*** :) 
   This is also able to delete & write into the files inside C:\<folder> i.e. /cygdrive/c/<folder>
3. ***With Cygwin 3.2*** :( 
   The problem is with this Cygwin version (not sure until what version above Cygwin 2.4 it is working fine). When I try to delete anything from the C:\<folder> i.e. /cygdrive/c/<folder> it is giving me the above **error**. File a.txt exists inside this folder.

/cygdrive/c/folder

```
$ rm a.txt
rm: cannot remove 'a.txt': Invalid argument
```

The strace for the above command shows error 0xC000000D through which the exact cause of this is not clear.

```
128   87299 [main] rm 1204 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path /cygdrive/c/folder/a.txt, dst C:\folder\a.txt, flags 0x6020, rc 0 
385   87684 [main] rm 1204 symlink_info::check: 0x0 = NtCreateFile (\??\C:\folder\a.txt)
135   87819 [main] rm 1204 symlink_info::check: not a symlink 
136   87955 [main] rm 1204 symlink_info::check: 0 = symlink.check(C:\folder\a.txt, 0xFFFFB6B0) (mount_flags 0x6020, path_flags 0x0)
127   88082 [main] rm 1204 path_conv::check: this->path(C:\folder\a.txt), has_acls(1)
127   88209 [main] rm 1204 _unlink_nt: Trying to delete \??\C:\folder\a.txt, isdir = 0
842   89051 [main] rm 1204 _unlink_nt: \??\C:\folder\a.txt, return status = 0xC000000D
131   89182 [main] rm 1204 seterrno_from_nt_status: /home/corinna/src/cygwin/cygwin-3.2.0/cygwin-3.2.0-1.x86_64/src/newlib-cygwin/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc:1145 status 0xC000000D -> windows error 87
139   89321 [main] rm 1204 geterrno_from_win_error: windows error 87 == errno 22
```

Comment: Make sure that you are executing the right command. At the bash prompt, `type rm` should return `rm is /usr/bin/rm` or `rm is aliased to ...` which ends up at /usr/bin/rm.

Comment: In the strace `has_acls(1)` means that there are windows acls in addition to the POSIX permissions. So use `lsacls` to see the acls on the file, and the folder containing the file.

Comment: If you are running a script, and `rm` is aliased to `rm -i`, check `rm --help` to see what that means.

Comment: I did "whereis rm" which is correctly saying "/usr/bin/rm".